# an element in appearing in view could not find it under "Elements in Dev tools"

Tags: javascript, dojo

in Dojo widgets, if you add Title to html elements and when you hover over it, you get "Tooltip" like function without adding any code(I got to know that _WidgetBase.js is doing it). what is confusing for me is I cannot see it(Tooltip) in DOM.  Anything displayed in Page should be visible under Elements tab in developer tools right. Please see the attached image.

In the attached image, `<span title="i am a new text">a dummy implement</span>` , when we hover over this element, we get a popup like function, but I could not find this popup under Elemnts in Dev tools. Please help me what I am missing.

[image]

Comment: If I am not wrong, Elements under Dev tools get updated with whatever changes(made by Ajax, Javascript...) the  page View undergo in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML, the text in `title` attribute renders automatically as a tooltip. So the page you posted may not be using any other element for this.

```html
<span title="i am a new text">a dummy implement</span>
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title

Comment: Thanks for the help, Gabriel. But why the tooltip thing is not shown as element under Elements in Dev tools ( because whatever in view should have an associated HTML element like div, p, span...etc right ). I am seeing this scenario 1st time in JavaScript.

Comment: That is because the `title` is an attribute, not an element. And the capacity to show a tooltip is a function built-in browsers (not sure about the last part).